# Unity OnTriggerEnter2D CompareTag || CompareTag inconsistency

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a generic "Snake" game using Unity in order to reinforce my knowledge of C# and Unity fundamentals.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the player to Game Over when colliding with the body. Currently I have the collision check set up like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Border") || other.gameObject.CompareTag("Body")) //if the player collides with a Border tag or Body tag...
    {
        //Game Over Sequence
        GameOver();
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Collectable")) //otherwise if the player collides with a Collectable tag...
    {
        //Snek needs to grow!
        shouldGrow = true;
    }
}
```

Here's a picture of the snake body's prefab inspector as well. I checked to make sure the tag is set to Body.

[image]

The border collision is working fine, and the strange part is setting the border object to the "Body" tag is also working fine, so I'm not sure why the body segments aren't triggering the Game Over sequence.

I'm new to programming, so apologies if this question is obvious, but I don't understand why this isn't working.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Per Programmer's request, here's an image of one of the Border's inspectors:

[image]

Comment: `||` means that if it collides with Border **or** Body the if statement will be true. Put `Debug.Log("hit");` before calling `GameOver();` function and let me know if you see the message when you collider with Border or Body.

Comment: The message appears when colliding with the Border as well as when colliding with the Border sprite when setting its type to "Body" (as an additional check). It does **not** appear when colliding with the snake's body segments. It seems like the "Body" tag and If statement are working correctly, but for some reason the prefab itself is not triggering the collision. I double-checked the Snake_Body (Copy) object during runtime as well and it sill has the "Body" tag, so I'm still lost.

Comment: The only way to find out if what you said is true is to remove `other.gameObject.CompareTag("Border") ||` for now and just test for the `Body` at this time. If it is still not working, EDIT your question, select the "Border" in unity, take a screenshot of it and the settings and upload it here too just like you did for the Body.

Comment: Tried it as you described, still does not call the `Debug.Log("hit")` message or the `GameOver();` function when colliding with the snake's body. I've added a screenshot of a border's inspector as requested.

Comment: `Trigger` is not checked in the Snake_Body. Just check that.

Comment: never use "else if" for any reason, @SolAureus .  you absolutely don't understand what it does, and you should not use it.

Comment: Could you help me understand why it's wrong within that context then? Maybe point me in the direction of an explanation? It kind of comes off as rude to just say "you don't understand this so never use it", especially when it comes to programming. I come on this site in order to seek to understand problems within my code, not to just be told "you're doing it wrong". My understanding of else if is "if (conditions to check) {stuff to do if conditions are met}; else if (if the first conditions aren't met, check these conditions before breaking) {different stuff to do if second conditions are met}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tick 'is Trigger' on the Snake_Body's box collider. Without this the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function is not called. You have done this correctly on the border box collider.

Comment: Yes, that's it. From both pictures he uploaded. +1

Comment: Yeah, I must admit, I was staring at this for 20 mins before I saw it! The second inspector photo made it obvious.

Comment: Well. I feel a bit silly since it was something so simple and obvious haha...well thank both of you for your help!